# Configure GPIO pin for infrared interface (IRTIM) of STM32F030x4/x6/x8

Tags: gpio, register, stm32f0

I have a problem for use infrared interface (IRTIM) of my MCU. When I saw in [Reference manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/DM00091010.pdf) I could find this:

[image]

Now, when I search for find GPIOx_AFRx register, I cannot find this register in reference manual.

Where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual register isn't named `GPIOx_AFRx`, the "x" is a placeholder for other designators.

In this case, the first "x" is a placeholder for a numbered general purpose I/O, and the second "x" is a placeholder to indicate the alternate function **low** or **high** register.

If you look at sections 8.4.9 and 8.4.10 (PDF page 128) of the document you linked, you'll find they deal with the `GPIOx_AFRL` and `GPIOx_AFRH` for the low and high registers, respectively.

Comment: Thanks, I have confused a bit because I don't know How exactly should I configure these registers for TIM16 and TIM17?

Comment: I'm not familiar with TIM16/17; I'd recommend asking that as a separate (new) question.